# Preserve the desktop where an application's window was placed, after a system restart

Tags: macos, spaces, restart

As the image below shows, I've a few applications which I keep open on my main desktop and I've another `space`/Desktop for applications like `Twitter for Mac`, `Stickies`, etc.

[image: Spaces setup on my Macbook Pro]

Now, the problem is that when I restart the system (I use the setting - "Reopen Windows when logging back in"), all the application windows which are opened on the Desktop 2 come up on the Desktop 1, instead of Desktop 2 where they were present originally. Is there a way to preserve their location after the restart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution that's working for me, and now my application windows doesn't switch Desktop randomly on restart.

For the two desktop setup as in the question, first I go to the desktop where I want to stick an application window. Say, we want to stick web browser to desktop 1, we

1. go to desktop 1,
2. open the application on this desktop,
3. right click on the application icon on the dock, then `Options` > `Assign to` > `This desktop`
4. similarly, stick applications on desktop 2

Now, after system restart, the applications are starting where they were sticked!

Comment: this does not work if I want to stick two windows of the same application in different spaces

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/#divvyMac) to keep all your windows in check ?

Comment: I am not positive but I think Divvy was breaking my "Assign to Desktop" feature.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug that needs to be fixed by Apple. What also happens that switching between applications on different desktops would switch to that desktop and the application's menu would be displayed, but none of the application's windows would be coming to the front. To add to that, also the Finder wouldn't stick to the option of "All Desktops" at random times as far as my poor attention to what caused it goes.

If Divvy is free maybe you should give it a try until that bug is fixed.